# Is this correct: Might I request it remain as it is?

Tags: subject-verb-agreement

Which of the two is correct?

1. Might I request it remain as it is?
2. Might I request it remains as it is?

Can both be correct?

Comment: Hello Zeus.  You have asked a "which one is correct" type of question.  These can be answered but it would help if you gave some background.  Why do you think there is a problem with either of these? What situation or context do you want to use this phrase. Have you seen either phrase used by a native speaker of English.   Usually "which one is correct" questions need more details to be useful.